# Ошибка при запуске cgi скрипта на сайте: Premature end of script headers

Tags: python, cgi

Пытаюсь запустить скрипт на питоне, получаю ошибку 500. Интерпретатор и кодировку указал.

Лог ошибок содержит:

> Premature end of script headers

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literal
print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print ('<html>')
print ('<head>')
print ('<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>')
print ('</head>')
print ('<body>')
print ('<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>')
print ('</body>')
print ('</html>')
```

Comment: какой скрипт? Какой командой пытаетесь запустить и как пытаесь получить результат?

Comment: открытием файла py, который просто должен вывести слова в качестве теста

Comment: 500 - ошибка сервера, значит не просто запуск ру файла... Обычно, такая реакция на ошибки компиляции, попробуйте запустить таки ру файл... Из того, что вижу, после заголовка оставьте только \n: `print ("Content-type:text/html\n")`. У меня так работает...

Comment: У вас опечатка в третьей строчке